# Convert JSON to XML in C#

Tags: c#, .net, json, xml

I have code like this:

method call and defination :

```
List<JiraProject> projects = manager.GetProjects();

public List<JiraProject> GetProjects()
{
    List<JiraProject> projects = new List<JiraProject>();
    string strAutho = runQuery(JiraResource.project); //,null,null,"GET"
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strAutho))
    {

    }
    //return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JiraProject>>(strAutho);
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(strAutho, "root");
}
```

I'm using Newtonsoft json 3rd party lib to convert this to XML. The Error I'm getting:

> Can not implicitly convert xml document to <List>

so I changed the type like :

```
return JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(<List<JiraProject>>strAutho, "root");
```

Still getting same type of error. How to correct this?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do here.  You say you want to convert this to XML (which your code will do), but your return type is `List<JiraProject>` - that isn't anything to do with XML, hence the error.  So what is it you want to return?

Comment: provide us with a sample of `strAutho`

Answer (score 3):

Json.NET supports converting JSON to XML and vice versa using the XmlNodeConverter.

```
// To convert an XML node contained in string xml into a JSON string   
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);

// To convert JSON text contained in string json into an XML node
XmlDocument doc = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json);
```

Json.NET Documentation:  [Converting JSON and XML](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConvertingJSONandXML.htm)

[How to convert JSON to XML and vice versa in C#](http://www.dotnetthoughts.net/how-to-convert-json-to-xml-and-vice-versa-in-c/)

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you exactly what is wrong: [`JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeXmlNode_1.htm) returns an `XmlDocument`. You cannot cast that to `List<T>`.

Answer (score -1):

It seems you want to convert list to XML.

Please refer if it helps: [C# serialize List of string to XML](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0a5aa658-7276-42e5-9d9e-b786694d6020/c-serialize-liststring-to-xml?forum=csharpgeneral)

Also, you need to check the method's return type as the return type is List but you want to return XML.

Comment: Explain the solution that you find.